# get the value of the array named texbox in angular js

Tags: angularjs

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="question in questions">
<div class="item item-divider">
{{question.text}}
</div>
<div ng-repeat="option in question.option">
<ion-radio ng-model="user.answer" name="{{$parent.question.id}}" ng-value="option.value">      {{option.text}}</ion-radio>
</div>
</div>
```

The Above lines display a list of question with the option user has to answer the question and submit it.
How can i submit the form and get the answer of the question. Here I have used name as question id to know which question answer it is.Now how i can save the answer and question id.Here ng-model=user.answer post only last question answer how to get all the question answer.